# How to retrieve image url from Google images?

Tags: html, c++, image, url

I'm creating a desktop app in C++, and I'm trying to implement a drag and drop feature : the user drags an image from an integrated Google Images search webpage into an area of the app, and the app downloads the full image.

So far, when I drag the image from the Google Images search, the URL associated with the drop is not really the full resolution image itself. It rather gives me something like [this](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fimages.sftcdn.net%2Fimages%2Ft_app-cover-l%2Cf_auto%2Fp%2Fbefbcde0-9b36-11e6-95b9-00163ed833e7%2F260663710%2Fthe-test-fun-for-friends-screenshot.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fthe-test-fun-for-friends.fr.softonic.com%2Fiphone&docid=BQMuJHr8FLJEaM&tbnid=hj6en-hBZN-VPM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwjjs9G7nPbiAhULmeAKHXIPB68QMwhIKAAwAA..i&w=1020&h=574&bih=674&biw=290&q=test&ved=0ahUKEwjjs9G7nPbiAhULmeAKHXIPB68QMwhIKAAwAA&iact=mrc&uact=8).

I know there are Chrome extensions that brings the `View Image` button back, and I downloaded the source code for one of them to get some inspiration, but they are written in JavaScript and, even though I plan on learning JS in the near future, it would be sweet if I could do it without it at the moment.

Comment: What portion of the js code did you not understand? Maybe we can help. Or show us how exactly you go aboot retrieving the URL that is supposed to contain the 'real image'.

Comment: The JS code is as follows : ```var image = object.querySelector('img[alt^="Image result"][src]:not([src^="https://encrypted-tbn"]).irc_mut, img[src].irc_mi');``` . The developer comments indicate that this exact line retrieves the image. As for my code, the only thing the user should do is dragging the image from the google search webpage (you can try it for yourself, when you drag it to your desktop, it creates a shortcut file containing a link, which redirects to the google search page, not the image real url, and that's what I'm trying to achieve).

Comment: Ok now i understand your intention. I'd probably go aboot it by first retrieving the webpage from that URL and then crawling through its links for the 'real image'.